# VC++ code explanation

Tags: visual-c++

can anyone explain me this code in the header file

```
#define MYAPI =__stdcall                     
typedef unsigned long VHANDLE;   
void  MYAPI EntityErase (VHANDLE hEnt, BOOL bErase);
```

Mainly what's  `MYAPI` doing

thanks in advance

Comment: You should really invest into an introductory C programming language book

Comment: @Shirish Is the preprocessor directive ended with a `;` or it's a typo. Any how it is just a text replacement which doesn't matter though.

Comment: When possible, it's better to cut-n-paste code into your question, rather than re-type it. As-is, your macro definition still has a typo (the `=`) that will prevent the code from compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MYAPI` is called a macro. In the first phase of compilation (prepossessing phase) the compiler replaces every occurence of it by `__stdcall`

`__stdcall` changes the calling convention of `EntityErase()` function, it is rather a compiler technical details so I'm not sure you should care about it.

Comment: +1 -- but be careful with the word "phase" here. The C++ standard defines "phases of translation", and macro expansion is actually the fourth phase.

Comment: @JerryCoffin what term should be used then?

Comment: Good question. I think I'd just say "early in the compilation process", or something on that order.

Answer (score 1):

MYAPI is defined as _stdcall which is a calling conventions used by the compiler.

To learn more about calling conventions read this article : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions